# Views: Return the nodes either side of current node

Tags: views

Is there a way in views to return 1 node that was published before the current node being viewed and the 1 node after?

Currently I have a view using a contextual filter which is the current NID from URL but I can't find a way to pass that to the filter criteria.

Is it possible? It can be split in to 2 views if needed so in 1 I get the previous node and the other I get the next one.

e.g.

current nid = 2

View returns 1, 3

Comment: Do you want to get links for the nodes or entire nodes ?

Comment: In the view it'll be pulling out fields.

Comment: fields of nodes ? If you want fields of nodes then my answer below will provide function to fetch previous and next nid also. Use nid and you can fetch desired fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Previous/Next API](http://drupal.org/project/prev_next) to get the previous and next nodes of particular nodes.
It also provides Views plugin to display Previous/Next links in View.

Comment: did what I needed it to do. Documentation is a little thin on the ground

Comment: Can you explain how to get this option in views.there is no extra options in views related to the prev/next api.